# Changing google drive embedded video thumbnail

Tags: html, iframe, google-drive-api

When I copy past iframe tag provided by Google Drive for embedding a video:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7Q8Ho-0TCaGjkVU2295SaPBDLXBGPK/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

It gets rendered something like this:

[image: image url]

How can I change the thumbnail (that is the video image behind play button above) which is shown in embedded video?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the thumbnail of video file cannot be directly changed. So, as a workaround, how about using `video controls` instead of `iframe`? In this case, the thumbnail can be changed. But I'm not sure about your actual situation from your question. So this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.